# Emacs Dired rename with alternative tool

Tags: emacs, dired

In dired you can rename files just by editing the directory listing and then saving it.

Is it possible to use use an alternative method for renaming when using dired for renaming? I want to use "svn mv", "bzr mv" or "git mv" instead of just renaming, so that I can register the extra metadata in the source control system.

Comment: For git mv, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610365/how-to-use-git-mv-from-magit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the functions in `dired-aux.el`, it seems like the built-in `rename-file` is what is ultimately called by `dired-rename-file` (which is the function bound to 'R' in `dired-mode`).

What you could do is grab that function and replace the call to `rename-file` with a call to `shell-command` that runs the appropriate VCS command.

However, another (better/easier) option would be to use one of Emacs's VCS modes to rename your files in your revision control system directly -- have a look at [magit](http://zagadka.vm.bytemark.co.uk/magit/) or [PSVN](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SvnStatusMode#toc2) or [MercurialMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MercurialMode), depending on your choice of poison...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think dired provides any hook for that. You may be stuck doing something like

```
! hg mv ? target
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set variable `dired-vc-rename-file` to `t` in your file `.emacs`:

```
(setq dired-vc-rename-file t)
```

If the value of the variable is non-nil and the renamed files are under version control, then dired will rename them using ‘vc-rename-file’ which for git applies `git mv`.