# Emacs dired and bazaar

Tags: version-control, emacs, bazaar, dired

I started using Emacs dired mode to move some files in a bazaar repository into a new folder in the repository. I then ran `bzr add` to get bazaar to find these "new" files, and then realized that when committing, bazaar would consider the original files as missing and commit the moved files as new files (?). Is there a method in Emacs to make dired VCS-aware, so that it will execute `bzr mv` instead of `mv`?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233344/emacs-dired-rename-with-alternative-tool).

**Solution:** I created the new folder in the repository and then ran `bzr add` so that bzr is aware of the folder. I then moved files from the root of the repository into the new folder using `mv` (not `bzr mv`) and then ran `bzr mv --auto` to detect the moves. bzr showed that it had detected the moves of each of the files, rather than removing the original and adding the files in the new location. I then tested this further by moving a file into the folder from within Emacs dired mode and running `bzr mv --auto` and again bzr detected the move correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question about dired, but note that `M-x vc-rename-file` should execute the appropriate command for whichever VCS you are using.

Comment: That can be run from within dired mode?

Comment: Yes, it's an autoloaded function, so it ought to work from anywhere by default.