# How to use git mv from magit?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

Is there a nice way to call `git mv` on a file from within magit? I know it's possible to run any git command with <kbd>:</kbd>, but this won't autocomplete filenames.

Comment: Just for information: what do you think `git mv` does? Do you realize that git does not track moves? git mv will just rename the file, remove the old name from the index and adds the new one.

Comment: Yep, it's just as everything else in magit is basically one/two keypress(es), I was hoping there was something for `mv`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure offhand if there's a direct way, but...

Given that a `mv` *is* the same thing as a `rm` plus an `add`, you can just rename the file normally (e.g. in dired), and then stage both of the consequent changes -- a deleted file and a new file.

Git should figure it out.

**Edit:**

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `vc-rename-file` ?

Comment: This works, but I was looking for something to do it automagically. `: mv /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2` (from a magit buffer) is even quicker, but it doesn't autocomplete.

Comment: Excellent, `vc-rename-file` does what I want!

Comment: How do I do force the `git mv`? I'm getting the error: "Please update files before moving them"

Comment: nnyby: So I'm guessing there are unmerged changes to the file you're trying to move, so you should do as it says and merge in those changes first, otherwise I expect they'll be lost. If you're 100% certain you don't want the changes, the `-f` option might do the trick. (Failing that, you could always just copy the file, and manually restore it after merging.)

Answer (score 23):

For reference at least in current verion of magit there is `magit-file-rename` which can be invoked by <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: It would be nice to have `magit-file-move` too.

Comment: since magit buffer does not list tracked files, move the cursor to the last empty line and hit `R` to invoke magit-file-rename

Answer (score 8):

I use dired for this. `C-x d` when the file is open, then press `!` on the file to run `git mv ? newpath` command with the file as the `?` argument.

Comment: This doesn't change the directory of the emacs buffer, which I often forget to my own confusion...